# RabbitMQ consumer is slow

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I'm running RabbitMQ in a private EC2 on Amazon and I'm encountering some issues.

I've many consumers which read from the very same queue, and I experienced an unusual behavior in which, apparently, there is an upper limit on message per seconds read by the consumer.

These are the value I got:

> - 1 consumer, 60 m/s
> - 2 consumers, 30 m/s each, hence, 60 m/s
> - and so on.. capping at 60 m/s max.

I don't get what could be the bottleneck?

Comment: What's the message size? What's the EC2 instance type? Are you reading messages from the same machine? Maybe also some code would help.

Comment: Message size are quite big but I've experienced the same with short messages. It's a micro EC2 (we are just testing, it's not the production one).

And yes, we are reading messages from different machine.